# Why doesn't TextBox bind to Label in my XAML code?

Tags: c#, wpf

New to wpf applications. I tried to implement this code but the label is always blank no matter what I enter in the textbox:

```
<Window x:Class="Mufu.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Muf(u)" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,200,0,0" Name="textBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" />
    <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=textbox3, Path=Text}"  Height="48" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,30,0,0" Name="label4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="445" FontSize="26" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `textbox3` and `textBox3` are different names. Just change the case and it will work

Comment: Sigh...its always the logical errors that get me. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Stackpanel>
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,200,0,0" Name="textBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" />
    <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=textbox3, Path=Text}"  Height="48" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,30,0,0" Name="label4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="445" FontSize="26" />
</Stackpanel>
```